# error using react native /react-native-payments-alive library to do apple pay

Tags: react-native, applepay

Hope someone can help who has used react-native-payments-alive.

I have the following code

```
import {PaymentRequest} from 'react-native-payments-alive';
const METHOD_DATA = [{
        supportedMethods: ['apple-pay'],
        data: {
          merchantIdentifier: 'merchant.uat.com',
          supportedNetworks: ['visa', 'mastercard'],
          countryCode: 'USA',
          currencyCode: 'USD'
        }
      }];
const DETAILS = {
        id: 'simple-basket',
        displayItems: [
          {amount: "369.00", label: "Product 1 "},
          {amount: "10.00", label: "Shipping"}
        ],
        total: {
          label: 'Grand Total',
          amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '379.00'}
        }
      };

const paymentRequest = new PaymentRequest(METHOD_DATA, DETAILS);

paymentRequest.show()
              .then(paymentResponse => {
                console.log('paymentResponse ', paymentResponse)
                paymentResponse.complete('success');
              }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

I keep getting this error

Failed to construct 'PaymentRequest':  required member value is undefined.

Any help appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but they changed their how you need to send the data and its not updated on the docs of react-native-payments, went through their code,

```
const DETAILS = {
    id: 'simple-basket',
    displayItems: [
      {amount: { value: "369.00", currency: "USD" } , label: "Product 1 "},
      {amount: { value: "10.00", currency: "USD" }, label: "Shipping"}
    ],
    total: {
      label: 'Grand Total',
      amount: {currency: 'USD', value: '379.00'}
    }
  };
```

should work for you